# How to get the one day time interval for same date(day)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using following code to get the 24hours, I am passing mm/dd/yy format date as 11/20/14 to the following code.

```
$to_date = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', strtotime($to));
$from_date = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', strtotime($from));
```

What should I pass to get the todays (11/20/14) 24 hours?

I want a range when I compare  *$to_date* and *$from_date* that means the$from_date should be the start of the day and ** $to_date ** should be end of day 12 midnight.

Answer (score 0):

I think you seek for some like this:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'm/d/y', '11/20/14', new DateTimeZone('America/Halifax'));
$timestamp = $datetime->getTimestamp();    
$beginOfDay = strtotime("midnight", $timestamp);
$endOfDay   = strtotime("tomorrow", $beginOfDay) - 1;
```

Be sure, that you use correct timezone from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: can I pass 11/20/14 in $timestamp?

Comment: no, you should use `mktime(0,0,0,11,17,2014)` for timestamp creating. I'll add another way now

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$from_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$from 00:00:00"));
$to_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$to 23:59:59"));
```

this will work fine this case.